# netty in android has error could not find class ClientBootstrap

Tags: android, netty

I'm trying to run Echo example on Android's Emulator:

- The server is running well on my computer (windows 7)

- In OnCreate method of the AndroidWithNettyActivity(the class is created when I create Android project) I created new instance of AndroidEchoClient and invoke the run method.

When the Emulator start my activy (AndroidWithNettyActivity) it fails and show me dialog to force close.
Does anyone have experience about this problem?
In the log cat, there is error: [05-20 07:21:13.444: E/dalvikvm(325): Could not find class 'org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap', referenced from method Archer.Netty.Android.AndroidEchoClient.run]

It seems that the Emulator cannot find the ClientBootstrap class of netty's library (netty-3.4.5.Final.jar), but I don't know why because I already added netty's library in build path of my project.

Please help me, thank in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

That's my stupid mistake, I'm just resolved this issue by exporting the netty's library with my adroid app

Comment: I solved this problem by adding 'exported="true"' to .classpath file so that it become <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="netty-3.5.5.Final.jar"/>

Comment: I delete my library from class path in eclipse then I used this line and I clean the project and it works for me thanks